# Why Windows need much more time than Linux for updates?

Tags: operating-systems, maintenance

Why windows updates take ages to complete and need re-boot (sometimes 2x), but Linux updates run smoothly in the background while I still can work on the system (and only the kernel update needs re-boot)?

Being Windows the product of a single company, couldn't they have implemented some less disrupting update routine?

What's the technical reason below it?

Comment: I have never encountered a single windows update that requires multiple reboots in order to install.  If you are talking about a feature update, that isn't the same, and even then that only requires a single user-initiated reboot.

Comment: Windows has been monetized so that key features that provide income, such as telemetry, XBox and advertising are reinstalled with each major release. This makes updates *much* more time-consuming than simply installing only changed files.

Comment: If that was all there was to it, people would have stopped buying Windows years ago.

Answer (score 1):

As an example the Windows Servicing Stack analyzes shared libraries on a system and provides updates for them. It also does analysis to see if past updates need to be removed or patched.

Both of these approaches allow for a system to maintain backwards compatibility with any programs it may have installed by allowing for [multiple versions of shared libraries to exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly); therefore an update won't break an app that relies on an older version of a library.

Older libraries have more time for hackers to find exploits in them, and so these too, often have to be updated, even though they've already been superceeded.

On Linux, the latest updates are simply installed along with their dependencies. You can't roll back, and sometimes an update will cause an app to stop working.

The Windows Servicing Stack does determine if an update requires a reboot, and most updates do not, as you will find if you allow automatic updates to let Windows Update service the system, which can happen multiple times a day.

The Servicing Stack itself needs to be regularly updated, because it has quite a complex job.

Windows is servicing products going back remarkably far. I can't think of an OS that will continue to get updates while maintaining compatibility with applications going back decades.